# PyCharm pickle not recognising correct signature for pickle.dump() and pickle.load()

Tags: python, pycharm

Consider the following code (in picture below).

[image]

As you can see, PyCharm only expects one argument for `pickle.dump()` and no argument for `pickle.load()`, and that is clearly wrong. Does anyone else have a similar problem? I have had numerous problems with PyCharm's non-recognition of library functions. How do I fix this?

I'm using PyCharm Community 3.4.1 and Python 3.4.1.

EDIT (in response to the first couple of comments below):

Sometimes you may not reproduce the above problem easily. When I tried to reproduce it, the first time I type the code in a new PyCharm project, PyCharm didn't seem to complain. But the next day, when I re-opened the same thing, the problem started appearing. So, to reproduce the problem, you may need to restart PyCharm and or restart your machine.

Comment: cannot reproduce with pycharm 3.1.1

Comment: No problem with PyCharm 3.4.1 and Python 3.3.2.

Comment: @Ray - I can confirm this bug. I'm experiencing the same issue in PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1, while using Python 3.4.1. Any updates?

Comment: I think I manually edited the stub file associated with it, so it's not complaining now. Python stubs are files generated by PyCharm in situations where no Python source code for a library function is available, as in the case of `pickle.load()`. I can't quite remember what I did but I think I just manually changed the signature in the declarations in the sub files.