# PyCharm, what is python_stubs?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have had numerous problems with PyCharm not recognising functions in libraries properly, so I've decided to look into the source code of some example functions that PyCharm recognises incorrectly. For example, PyCharm does not recognise `pickle.load()` correctly; it thinks that `pickle.load()` does not take any arguments, when in fact it does take one argument. I've asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265572/pycharm-pickle-not-recognising-correct-signature-for-pickle-dump-and-pickle-lo). So I've written the following short testing code.

```
import pickle


r = range(10)
f = open("../temp/pickling_example.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(r, f)
f.close()
f = open("../temp/pickling_example.pkl", "rb")
pickle.load(f)
print(r)
```

I pressed `Ctrl+B` on `pickle.load(f)`, the penultimate line. I was hoping that this would bring me to the source file containing the definition of `pickle.load()`, but instead it brought me to a file in the location `C:\Users\ray\.PyCharm30\system\python_stubs\-1442825926\_pickle.py`. This file contains the following abstract (see screenshot below).

[image]

Here you can see the source of the problem of PyCharm incorrectly recognising the signature of `pickle.load()`; the signature of `pickle.load()` according to this file has no arguments.

Could someone explain why I was brought here, and what this file is, and what the `python_stubs` folder (more precisely, `C:\Users\ray\.PyCharm30\system\python_stubs\`) is?

My guess is the following. I was brought to this file in this location because PyCharm can't find the actual source code where `pickle.load()` was defined, on my computer. In these situations, PyCharm just generates a dummy file with just the declarations (or just the signatures) of the functions used, in this case it's `pickle.load()`. This file is where I was brought to when I pressed `Ctrl+B` on `pickle.load()`. The purpose of this file is purely so that PyCharm's inspections works properly and can provide autocompletion, and PyCharm puts all of these files inf the `python_stubs` directory. The actual definition of the `pickle.load()` function is in a `pyc` or `pyd` file somewhere in my `C:\Python34\` directory, and I don't have the actual `py` file containing the definition of `pickle.load()` because, when I installed Python, I didn't install the source codes.

Questions:

(1) Is my guess roughly correct? Could you provide and more correct and precise

(2) What can I do to prevent PyCharm from wrongly recognising or not recognising library functions? Shall I make sure I always install the source codes of Python and all 3rd party packages, in order to ensure that PyCharm can do its inspections properly?

(3) If I was right in that, PyCharm generates these files, how does PyCharm guess the functions' signatures?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(1) Yes, you are mostly correct.

The `python_stubs` file is an *automatically* generated file that contains dummy definitions for built-in functions. It is used by PyCharm to infer the types of the built-in functions in the case that they weren't hardcoded for the given version.

(3) It isn't always possible to correctly infer the type of a built-in functoin only from his docs. Some docstrings start with the "type signature":

```
>>> print(min.__doc__)
min(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
min(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
```

but `pickle.load()` doesn't.

Note that this will probably change in future python versions, because starting with python3.4 the [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.4.html#pep-436-argument-clinic) was introduced which allows better inspection for built-ins defined in C. I'm not sure whether PyCharm is already able to get that information.

(2) Try rebuilding the python skeletons. However, AFAIK, the only real option, if this doesn't work, is to open a ticket on [PyCharm's issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Wow thank you so much for actually reading through my really long question first of all, not to mention your brilliant answer! I don't really don't what a Python Skeleton is. Is that a Python concept or a PyCharm concept? Any pointers to a page where I can learn about skeletons?

Comment: @Ray It's a PyCharm related term. The "skeletons" are all the files that PyCharm automatically generates from the installed and built-in libraries that are required to provide its features. This includes generating the `python_stubs` file. When you launch PyCharm you can often see, in the status bar, some messages about rebuilding these skeletons for the project interpreter. You should be able to force the rebuild at restart invalidating the caches (under the `File` menu).

Answer (score 1):

PEP484 defined these [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files). As per the PEP, they are supposed to be for type-hints and can be used by type-checker.