# Python ctypes: where is _ctypes.py file supposed to be located?

Tags: python, ctypes

In my Python installation for `python3.7`, `ctypes` is installed.  For example, `__init__.py` is located in: `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py`.  This makes sense to me.

Note: my OS is MacOS Mojave, 10.14.3.

`ctypes` constantly refers to `_ctypes`.  I use PyCharm, and when I control-left click on `_ctypes`, it takes me to: `/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/PyCharmCE2018.3/python_stubs/-1199943126/_ctypes.py`.

Why is `_ctypes.py` in this random folder, and not in the folder installed with Python 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real `_ctypes.py`. That file you're seeing is something PyCharm created so it could show you fake source code. It's in that weird place because it's fake. I don't know why PyCharm does that.

The real source code for `_ctypes` is in C, and it doesn't make it into your Python distribution. You can see it in the CPython repository under the [`Modules/_ctypes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.7.3/Modules/_ctypes) folder. You can see where the compiled file for `_ctypes` is by importing `_ctypes` and inspecting `_ctypes.__file__`, but it's compiled, so for most purposes, you'll want to look at the source code instead.

Comment: Here is info on PyCharm and `python_stubs`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266114/pycharm-what-is-python-stubs

Comment: Also @user2357112, thank you for sharing the link to GitHub.  Where do you think I can find `cpython/Modules/_ctypes` folder on my local machine?  I don't see it in `site-packages` and a search of my Mac via Finder doesn't yield anything

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer: Like I said, it's probably not on your local machine at all.